# Any risks connecting to a Chinese printer?

Tags: security, printer

Ok, I fully admit this might be in the realm of paranoia, but hey, isn't that sort of the name of this game? :)

I'm staying in a hotel room and needed to buy a small, cheap laser printer for some printouts I need to do. After shopping far and wide, I decided the Pantum P2502W fit the bill perfectly- tiny footprint and more. But then the <paranoid|reasonably cautious> side of me started thinking- this is a Chinese company through and through. Sure, HP, Canon, and the like probably manufacture in China, but they're not Chinese companies at their core.

Anyway, perhaps this is all nuts. Perhaps a lowly printer literally can't do anything. But maybe it can (installing stuff- oh man, the drivers I just realized, or maybe saving info I'm sending to print, etc.) I'm no expert in this so wanted to check here.

There were also several (progressively less secure) layers of using it I wasn't sure about:

1. Simplest was going to be straight USB connection.
2. They also allow you to connect to it as a wireless hotspot to print (as opposed to it connecting to a local network for all devices to print). I guess at that point it has no internet connection so no worries?
3. There is some mobile app you can get to allow you to print from a mobile device. I assumed this was the least secure.

Well, I appreciate everyone's help. Perhaps this is nothing; perhaps I'm correct and I should return for a more established non-Chinese brand.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It's probably paranoia.

Note that it actually takes a lot of work to properly device a system that will steal your data without you noticing, so it's probably not going to happen.

If you can use the WiFi, at least you can block any connections from the printer to your computer. But as you mentioned, you have to install their driver. So those can most certainly do the job without even requiring the printer itself.

The App. on a mobile would certainly be pretty safe, only you'd have to accept them accessing your docs so you're in the same situation. Also that means your phone is "fried".

Anyway, if you need to do the printing and the printer doesn't accept a thumb drive, you'll have to connect. Otherwise you can forget the printer and go to a shop where you can just hand over the thumb drive. Your docs may be shared there too, but that would be limited to what you have to print (don't put anything else on the thumb drive).

Note that would have been a good question for the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) stack.